# rsync over multiplexed SSH connection and multiple jumphosts

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, rsync

I need to rsync a file from remote hosts to my local machine over multiple jumphosts. I'd like to use shared SSH connections so that I don't have to submit 2FA multiple times at some jumphosts.

The idea is I create a master connection

```
ssh user@jumphost01
```

then other connections

```
ssh -J user@jumphost01,user@jumphost02 root@target01
...
```

Shared connections control files in `~/.ssh/` look as follows

```
control:target01:22:root
control:jumphost01:22:user
control:jumphost02:22:user
```

Now I would expect I can rsync a remote file using

```
rsync -azv -e 'ssh -o ControlMaster=auto' root@target:/somePath/someFile someFile
or
rsync -azv root@target:/somePath/someFile someFile
or    
rsync -azv -e 'ssh -F /root/.ssh/config' root@target:/somePath/someFile someFile
```

but I'm getting rsync error

```
receiving incremental file list
someFile
WARNING: someFile failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).
someFile
ERROR: someFile failed verification -- update discarded.

sent 68 bytes  received 317 bytes  770.00 bytes/sec
total size is 305  speedup is 0.79
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1819) [generator=3.2.3]
```

Rsync is able to connect to the target but the file transfer is unsuccessful.

rsync versions

```
local machine - rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31
target machine - rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31
```

**TLDR;**

I tested the rsync command without SSH master connection as

```
rsync -azv -e 'ssh -J user@jumphost01,user@jumphost02' root@target01:someFile .
One-time password (OATH) for `user': 
Password: 
receiving incremental file list
someFile
WARNING: someFile failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).
someFile
ERROR: someFile failed verification -- update discarded.

sent 68 bytes  received 2,767 bytes  195.52 bytes/sec
total size is 18,976  speedup is 6.69
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1819) [generator=3.2.3]
```

And still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues with dynamically linked libraries.

```
# apt update && apt upgrade
```

on remote machine solved the issue.